# How to place a view over current view of activity?

Tags: android, layout

I am working with android.Is there any idea to place a view over the current view of the activity.I want to dynamically get the current view and the place my custom view over that current view .For example a gif image in the game screen .I had worked with inflater,but it doesn't work. Is it possible to make?? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can add the View to the decor view of your activity.

```
ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup) Activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
decor.addView(yourViewThatWillShowOnTopOfAllOthers);
```